# Instruction not waiting properly NodeJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I was wondering what is the problem here, why is the return statement not waiting to finish the previous instruction? `orders` are empty, even though I'm logging inside the `getOrders` to make sure there were data (there is data).

```js
await stores.forEach(async (store) => {
  let arr = await getOrders(store, token, tokenType);
  orders.push(arr);
})
return orders;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for all promises, you need an array of promises, which you can get using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Then you need to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), so that it will wait for all the promises in that array to complete.

```
const orders = await Promise.all(
  stores.map(store => getOrders(store, token, tokenType))
);
return orders;
```

*Edit: rewritten and simplified based on suggestion from @PatrickRoberts

To paraphrase his comment, in the old code when using a separate array with an `array.push`, the array ordering would be indeterminate. However using the array of results from `Promise.all` will always match the order of the original array.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That `Promise.all` means that each iteration is going to wait for the previous to finish?

Comment: No, `Promise.all` allows promises to run in parallel. But `all` won't resolve until all the promises in the collection have resolved.

Comment: Thank you, David! I really appreciate your help. I'll accept your answer in a couple of minutes :)

Answer (score -1):

It's a common misunderstanding that asynchronous callbacks (declared with async and called with await) passed to `forEach` or `map` will be executed synchronously or in order. Actually, they are not.

When you check the polyfill of those methods, you'll find a line like this callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);. So, basically, it just execute the callback. If the callback is an asynchronous method, it doesn't wait its execution to be done. Instead, it continue executing other codes.

Let's set an example using your code, let' say this is the callback:

```js
const callback = async (store) => {
  let arr = await getOrders(store, token, tokenType);
  orders.push(arr);
})
```

When it was passed to `forEach`:

```js
stores.forEach(callback);
```

basically, what `forEach` does is iterating the array, and call callback on each elements. May looks like this

```
...
loop {
  callback.call(...)
}
...
```

There is no wait here. However, each time, the code inside your `callback` is executed synchronously since it's declared with `async` and called with `await`, which means after `getOrders` is resolved and the result is pushed to `orders`.

So, if you want to execute the callbacks synchronously and in order, you may write a generic `for` loop.

```js
async function addOrders(){
  for(let store of stores) {
    let arr = await getOrders(store, token, tokenType);
    orders.push(arr);
  }
}

addOrders()
```